# Question on how to copy from one vector to another

Tags: vector, indexing, stl, copy

In C++, I have two STL vectors *double*, A and B both size 1200.  I want to copy all of B into A starting at a specific A index (which I know). The index may change, but B will always be copied entirely.  Is there a way to do this with iterators or is it just easier to copy each element with a FOR loop?

Comment: you will have to use a loop at least, a for loop it's basically a loop to increment iterator.

Comment: Say `k` is that specific index. Do you want to copy `B[k]` to `A[k]`, `B[k+1]` to `A[k+1]` and so on? Or `B[0]` to `A[k]`, `B[1]` to `A[k+1]` and so on? I'm not sure what you mean by "starting at a specific `A` index". Which value goes where?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to copy all of B into A starting at a specific A index (which I know)

`std::copy(B.begin(), B.end(), A.begin() + index)` will do this.

You have to ensure that `A.size() - index >= B.size()`, but that's doable.